# Vuetify: How to make v-html consider vuetify styling

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Is it possible to make the [v-html attribute](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-html) take Vuetify component styling in consideration? In the following example it renders the v-table content as text:

Code ([Playground link](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)):

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-container>
      <span v-html="content" />
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script setup>
  const content = `
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <body>

        <v-table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="text-left">
                Name
  </th>
              <th class="text-left">
                Calories
  </th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Frozen Yoghurt</td>
              <td>159</td>
                </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>Ice Cream Sandwich</td>
              <td>237</td>
                </tr>
  </tbody>
  </v-table>

  </body>
  </html>
 `
</script>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know why you would do.
Vue can inject HTML code with v-html directive, but it's not recommended. In this case you inject an entire table. It's a bad practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is working as expected, if you (inspect the element in dev tools you will see the code there) but the v-table tag is not recognised as a valid html tag, which breaks the html rendering.
Vue official documentation says:

#v-html

Contents of v-html are inserted as plain HTML - Vue template syntax will not be processed. If you find yourself trying to compose templates using v-html, try to rethink the solution by using components instead.